# Application helper to pass current client :id to collection form field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, helper

I have a rails app that has following models: 
`Users`, `clients` and `invoices`, In this app the `user` has the ability to create an `invoice` from the `invoices index view` and from the `clients show view`. Each `Invoice` is required to have the `:client_id` set on save. I am not calling `client.find(params:id)` in the `invoices_controller` `new action` because it cant be found when creating the `invoice` from the `invoices index view`.

What would be the best way to get the `current client :id` on `client/id/invoice.new` path? Should I pass `client :id` through in a helper method? Or can I do something cool in my `new action` or `form` that I am not seeing?

models

```
User
has_many :invoices
has_many :clients

Client
belongs_to :user
has_many :invoices

Invoice
belongs_to :client
belongs_to :user
```

In my invoices_controller new action I am just calling

```
def new
 @invoice = Invoice.new
end
```

My new invoice _form

```
<%= f.input_field :client_id, :collection => Client.all, :label_method => :client_name, :value_method => :id, :include_blank => false, selected: @client_id, class: "form-control" %>
```

And my routes

```
resources :invoices, only: [:new, :create, :destroy, :index]

resources :clients do
  resources :invoices, shallow: true
end

root 'invoices#index'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I create a new invoice at `clients/id/invoices/new`, I want to set the default form field selector to be the current client's id from the URL?

You need to pass `selected: value` option right after you pass `collection: []` to the `input_field` method like so:

```
<%= f.input_field :client_id, :collection => Client.all, :selected: @client_id, :label_method => :client_name, :value_method => :id, :include_blank => false, class: "form-control" %>
```

## Edit:

You may need to pass `@client` variable in URL helper like following:

```
new_invoice_path(client_id: @client.id, back_path: client_path(@client))
```

Comment: What's your question then?

Comment: When I create a new invoice at `client/id/invoice/new` I want to set the default form field selector to be the `client :id` from the url

Comment: I just re-wrote my answer.

Comment: So I want to set `:selected: @client_id` with the client id from the `new_client_invoice_path` right now the `:selected: @client_id` always defaults to client 1 even if the new invoice is for client 6

Comment: Just do `selected: params[:client_id]`, and then see what happens.

Comment: Nothing changes, It is still selecting the first `client_name`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106886/discussion-between-bilal-maqsood-and-aloalo).